# When is GC_CONCURRENT expected?

Tags: android, android-memory

Writing my first Android app at the moment, but have a reasonable understanding of multithreading from other programming languages. Something I'm noticing is the Log spitting out `GC_CONCURRENT` messages almost every time I finish an `AsyncTask` (and occasionally randomly). This doesn't happen that often since I have relatively few `AsyncTask`s, but it's enough to catch my attention - maybe one in every two fragments/activities started.

Is this acceptable, or correct? Is there a memory problem here? I've tried searching around this, most questions are obvious memory leaks in the form of infinite loops or lists - I'm not getting a huge dump of `GC_CONCURRENT` messages, just a one every few seconds of zooming round the app. Perhaps garbage collection of AsyncTask results? Most are JSON encoded strings from HTTP used only to read from into an `ArrayList<MyClass>` before being discarded.

Thanks in advance - apologies for a potentially trivial question, but I'd like to avoid getting into any bad habits/practices early on due to ignorance.

Comment: Normal garbage collection.  If you got dozens per second, you might worry.  One every few seconds is nothing to think about.

Comment: Thanks Simon - some peace of mind!

Comment: You're welcome.  Just found this, you might find it interesting - http://www.f15ijp.com/tag/gc_concurrent/